# How to reference a form data to use it in the form itself in Apex Oracle

Tags: oracle, forms, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create a form to add an order.

The form have a few entries where you can select:

- the product,
- the client,
- the number of items,
- the date of purchase and
- the total price.

Obviously, the date and the total price are not selectable. I want to calculate the total price, but I need to know the total items and the product name selected.

How can I enter that information without finishing the form?

Here is an image of the form, so you can understand easily what Im asking:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

1. Perform the update in the form. As soon as user changes price or number of items, the total price changes on screen. This type of action is called "Dynamic Action" in apex. You would create a dynamic action on both nr of items and product to calculate the price on change. There are many examples of dynamic actions on the internet.
2. Perform the update *after* the user has submitted the form. In this case you would create a "computation" on the total price item.

The end result in the database should be the same but the user experience is different.

Rgds
Koen

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done in a master-detail relationship:

- master table (and form) contains *general* information about the order
- detail table (and form, usually *tabular* or - nowadays, in Apex, an *interactive grid*) contains details about each item being ordered

It means that - if form your screenshot displays - is everything you have, you should consider changing data model. Otherwise, it can be done but is inefficient and isn't normalized so you should avoid it.

So: once you fill in details, you'll know which items were ordered, how many of each and how much each of those costs. Then it is easy to calculate totals. Just for example:

```
select o.order_number
       sum(i.number_of_items * i.current_price) total_per_order
from order o join items i on i.order_id = o.order_id
where o.order_number = 1234
group by o.order_number;
```